# auto reload (auto refresh) html page when cookie change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, jquery-cookie

how can html page auto reload when the cookie change?

I have this code in my main html page :

```
 body onload="set_style_from_cookie()"
```

when I change the style for the main html page from another page , how can the main page detect this change and auto reload?

Comment: How are the cookies changed? From JavaScript, or are they cookies that are set by the server? In the last case, you'll have to poll the server from the client to receive new cookies.

Answer (score 0):

this one will work :

I just included a timed interval to check if the cookie is changed:

> now if you open another window it will also be updated!

In this demo is only about background-color. but you can change it and add style you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function cookieWrite(name,value,days){var expires=""; if(days){var date=new Date(); date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*86400000)); expires="; expires="+date.toUTCString();} document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}
function cookieRead(name){var n=name+"="; var ca=document.cookie.split(";"); for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++){var c=ca[i]; while(c.charAt(0)==" "){c=c.substring(1,c.length);} if(c.indexOf(n)==0){return c.substring(n.length,c.length);}} return "";}
function cookieDelete(name){if(!name){var ca=document.cookie.split(";"); for(var i=0;i<ca.length; i++){var cv=ca[i].split("="); cookieWrite(cv[0],"",-1);}}else{cookieWrite(name,"",-1);}}

var mybgcolor="";
var cookieIntervall=setInterval(monitorCookie, 2000);

function set_style_from_cookie(bgcolor){
    if(typeof bgcolor=="undefined"){bgcolor=cookieRead("backgroundColor");}
    cookieWrite("backgroundColor", bgcolor, 7);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=bgcolor;
    mybgcolor=bgcolor;
}

function monitorCookie(){
    var bgcolor=cookieRead("backgroundColor");
    if(mybgcolor!=bgcolor) set_style_from_cookie(bgcolor);
};

window.addEventListener("load",function(){set_style_from_cookie();},false);
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div> <button type="button" onclick="set_style_from_cookie('blue')">BLUE</button> </div>
<div> <button type="button" onclick="set_style_from_cookie('black')">BLACK</button> </div>
<div> <button type="button" onclick="set_style_from_cookie('white')">WHITE</button> </div>
<div> <button type="button" onclick="set_style_from_cookie('red')">RED</button> </div>
<div> <button type="button" onclick="set_style_from_cookie('yellow')">YELLOW</button> </div>

<hr />
<div>refresh page to see that the BG-color will be read from cookie</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need any code , just I want a javascript code for always detecting the new cookies and reload the page after any new in this cookies @Federico

Comment: thx bro , but I want an auto reload when the cookie changes , in this time my code is like yours , but I want if I open 2 pages of my site and I choose the style from one , I want an auto reload for the second .. @Federico

Comment: Hi I finally understood what you needed, sorry.... now should work . just open the site in two windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like this that will check your cookie every `0.1 seconds`

```
//keep track of our cookie
var cookieRegistry = [];

function listenCookieChange(cookieName, callback) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (cookieRegistry[cookieName]) {
            if (readCookie(cookieName) != cookieRegistry[cookieName]) {
                // update registry so we dont get triggered again
                cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName);
                return callback();
            }
        } else {
            cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName);
        }
    }, 100);
}


function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

bind it

```
listenCookieChange('cookiename', function() {
    Location.reload();
});
```

this will however execute this script `10x` per second so you may want to change this. To do so change the '`100`'. (if you change it to `1000` it wil check once every second).

Comment: I put the 3 codes in a checkCookies.js and I put : script type="text/javascript" src="checkCookies.js" in the main.html , but nothing happened when cookies change . We must put a onload function or what ? thx @Jasper

Comment: I dont understand well , my code for style ( themes ) is : 
var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 20*365 ;

Comment: function switch_style ( css_title )
{

    var i, link_tag ;
    for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
         i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
        if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
            link_tag[i].title) {
            link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
            if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
                link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
            }
        }
        set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
                   style_cookie_duration );
    }
}

Comment: function set_style_from_cookie()
{
    var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
    if (css_title.length) {
        switch_style( css_title );
    }
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
                     lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
   
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
    ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
    "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
    "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
    24 * lifespan_in_days +
    "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}

Comment: function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                                                '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                                                cookie_name +
                                                '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}